# my code for sha256 algorithm in python doesn't except length of above 56 characters (448 bits)

Tags: python, algorithm, security, hash, sha256

As far as I understand, the problem is caused when I pad the message with zeros until it is a multiple of 512. If the padding results in a padded message length of 512 it works but if the message in bits >= 448, padded message length = 1024, and it doesn't work.

I don't know how to use each chunk of data for the word list or for the compression part.

- Does anyone know how each block (64 bytes) is processed?
- Do I have to create a different Word list for each 512 bits?

I tried using test vectors but they were quite unhelpful.

I'm hashing `ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223bda12ae1a5324sfdserew3ra` using sha256 algorithm.

**Correct hash value**: `1caa150674ab1aed030dc69f9b86dbcbc412e6e1dd20344eeaa21687acae7789`

**My result**: `efcf3579753ef16f9f515f61d901eaafa03aafa6b9e092fe3d087efdfd25c41e`

My definition of the padding of word list:

```py
self.convertToBytes = "".join(format(ord(char), "08b") for char in msg)

padding = (512 - len(self.add1) - 64) % 512

self.zFill = self.add1 + "".zfill(padding)

# add ascii value of length of msg's to zFill
# the length of self.addlen is always a multiple of 512
self.addlen = self.zFill + format(len(self.convertToBytes), "08b").zfill(64)[0:64]
addtoW = [
    self.addlen[i : i + 32]  # seperated each 32 bits into a list; Each entry = 32 bits.
    for i in range(0, len(self.addlen), 32)
]

# length of self.W is always 64 no matter the length of message
# if len(addtoW) < 64:
self.W = addtoW + [
    "".zfill((64 - len(addtoW)) * 32)[i : i + 32] for i in range(0, 64 - len(addtoW))
]
```

Comment: When implementing any cryptographical algorithm (be it a hash or a cipher), you should not be thinking about "ascii values" but bytes instead...

Comment: AKX, this is the first hashing algorithm I coded and the test vectors I used had ASCII values so for comparing, I also used ASCII values.